# session login - IE error

Tags: php, session-state

I am trying to get my session login script working and I had the obvious header issues so I added this to the top of my page and it now allows login on Chrome browsers but not IE, the page only displays what is in my included header file (no css) its like it is just ignoring everything else.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']))
{               
    $username = $_SESSION["SESS_USERNAME"];             
    echo '<div id="session">You are logged in as '.$username.'</div>';
}
else
{    
    header("Location: index.php");  
}
?>
```

Any reasons why??

Comment: "my included header file" - I did not understand this part

Comment: `include('header.html');` <--this

Comment: The PHP is executed at the server-end. So, if it is not working in IE, it should not work in chrome either. Check page sources, they must be the same. Are you being displayed a cached version of one page?

Comment: Try this:
create a file: another.php `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['testing']=TRUE; ?>` then test this session variable in your file.

Comment: the sessions work - but something in this is stopping the rest of the page to not read. When i close browser and go to home page it redirects to my login page as it should but something is stopping the rest of my page in IE. :( this code it placed right at the top of my page.

Comment: I just took the echo out of the code and it seems thats the problem for some reason - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you've turned off cookies in IE. Check it! If yes, turn it on and then try again.
It'll work

Comment: it doesnt return the header so the session is reading true its just the rest of my web page is not there just the text you are logged in is as :$username. part of my navigation (drop downs dont work) and the rest is blank white.

Comment: @Oliver-Bush Enable error reporting (and ini_set to display errors). So there is something more than a blank white page.

Comment: Removing the `echo etc...` allowed the page to load again as per usual.